# Any way to know the file to which a FileReader is pointing at?

Tags: java, junit, testng, filereader, filewriter

I'm trying to test this piece of Java code with TestNG framework:

```
public static void createFileIfNotExists(String path) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }
}

public static File getFile(String path) throws IOException{
    createFileIfNotExists(path);
    return new File (path);
}

public static FileWriter initiateFileWriter (String path) throws IOException{
    return new FileWriter (getFile(path),false);
}


public static FileReader initiateFileReader (String path) throws IOException{
    return new FileReader (getFile(path));
}
```

The test class I have is the following (tests for createFileIfNotExists(String path) and getFile(String path) both have passed):

```
File expectedFile, actualFile;
String path;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    path = "fixtures\\prueba.txt";
    expectedFile = new File(path);
}

@BeforeGroups(groups = "IOReader")
public void setUpIOReader() throws IOException {
    FileBody.createFileIfNotExists(path);
}

public void testCreateFileIfNotExists() throws IOException {
    FileBody.createFileIfNotExists(path);
    assertTrue(expectedFile.exists());
}

public void testGetFile() throws IOException {
    actualFile = FileBody.getFile(path);
    assertEquals(expectedFile, actualFile);
}


public void testInitiateFileWriter() throws IOException {
    FileWriter expectedFileWriter = new FileWriter(expectedFile,false);
    FileWriter actualFileWriter = FileBody.initiateFileWriter(path);
    assertEquals(expectedFileWriter, actualFileWriter);
    expectedFileWriter.close();
    actualFileWriter.close();
}

@Test(groups = {"IOReader"})
public void testInitiateFileReader() throws IOException {
    FileReader expectedFileReader = new FileReader(expectedFile);
    FileReader actualFileReader = FileBody.initiateFileReader(path);
    assertEquals(expectedFileReader, actualFileReader);
    expectedFileReader.close();
    actualFileReader.close();
}
```

But tests for initiateFileWriter and initiateFileReader both failed because of these reasons:

initiateFileReader Failure:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:java.io.FileReader@53a07924 but was:java.io.FileReader@4c715560

initiateFileWriter Failure:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:java.io.FileWriter@4960e09f but was:java.io.FileWriter@773b0c5b

I think it is because expected and actual `FileWriter`/`FileReader` are different objects among them but... is it not supposed that the `assertEquals` method compare if two objects are equivalent rather than pointing to the same instance?

Does exist a method to call from a `FileWriter`/`FileReader` and know to which file they are pointing at? Because in this way I can solve the problem like this:

```
assertEquals(expectedFileWriter.getFileToWhichI'mPointing(),actualFileWriter.getFileToWhichI'mPointing())

assertEquals(expectedFileReader.getFileToWhichI'mPointing(),actualFileReader.getFileToWhichI'mPointing())
```

Comment: `FileReader` does *not* override `equals()`, so two different `FileReader`s will never be equal. I assume the same applies for `FileWriter`.

Comment: You don't need the first two methods. `new FileWriter()` is perfectly capable of creating a file without any assistance from you. You don't need the other two either: just call `new FileWriter()` and `new FileReader()` directly in your code. That leaves you nothing to test, and eliminates the whole problem. You seem to be just testing the platform anyway. Don't waste your time doing that. Your test code is longer than the code you're testing, none of which was necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method on `FileReader`/`FileWriter` to tell you what file it points to (because theoretically you should never need to know - that's why you're working with the reader and not the `File`).

You could use reflection to read private fields of the underlying `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`.

But I think the correct approach to this is ***don't test things that cannot break*** - namely, don't test the Java core libraries. Unless the code posted is a simplified version, `testInitiateFileWriter()` is effectively testing `new FileWriter (getFile(path),false)`, and you already know that `getFile(path)` works (as per your passing test), so the only thing you're testing here is `new FileWriter(...)`.

Footnote: Of course Java libraries *can* break / contain bugs, but the chance is negligible in most cases and for such widely-used part as FileReader/FileWriter.

Comment: Thank you. You're totally right. While I was trying to decloupe my code, I commited the error to write a method only to simulate the  <code>FileInputStream/FileOutputStream<code> functionality and this have little sense